# Change color of two text field

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

My static table view has two separate groups of fields:

```
 Group 1
     Row 1: UITextField - emailOne 
     Row 2: UITextField - confirmEmailOne

 Group 2
     Row 3: UITextField - emailTwo
     Row 4: UITextField - confirmEmailTwo
```

I would want to change a field's color according to the next logic: then I type in a character in emailOne it should immediately check if it is equal to the text of confirmEmailOne field. If it is not - it should spotlight both of fields: emailOne and confirmEmailOne.  I connected email fields to the storyboard:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var firstEmailOne: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var firstEmailTwo: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var secondEmailOne: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var secondEmailTwo: UITextField!
```

After, I added this field in array in `viewDidLoad` and add targets:

```
 comparableArray[firstEmailOne] = 1
 comparableArray[firstEmailTwo] = 1
 comparableArray[secondEmailOne] = 2
 comparableArray[secondEmailTwo] = 2
 for row in comparableArray {            
     row.key.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
 }
```

And here `@objc func`:

```
 @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let groupOfField = comparableArray[textField]
    var checkedArray = [UITextField]()
    for row in comparableArray {
        if row.value == groupOfField {
            checkedArray.append(row.key)
        }
    }
    if checkedArray[0].text == checkedArray[1].text {
          // Error here: the color does not change.
          checkedArray[0].textColor = UIColor.black
          checkedArray[1].textColor = UIColor.black

    } else {
          // Error here: the color does not change.
          checkedArray[0].textColor = UIColor.red
          checkedArray[1].textColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

The problem: the color does not change on both fields. It always changes in a field with current focus. I tried to execute `checkedArray[0].textColor` in `DispatchQueue.main` but it didn't change anyway.

Comment: Why not use a IBOutletCollection and simplifying a bit your code you can achieve what you need

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have never heard about IBOutletCollection :) I am going to try it out.

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you. You were right. It is much easer to do that with IBOutletCollection.